# Converting a Create table sql script to pyspark code

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyspark, teradata

I'm creating a automated pyspark code to convert SQL script to Pyspark script.
-) Structure the code such that it is a general code and can be run for similar texts without hardcoding any table name or column names.
-)And only 1st name can be considered for creating the table the rest can be discarded

```
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE VT_PASS7PRE, NO LOG, NO FALLBACK
AS
(
SEL
COUNT(1) CNT,
SYSTEM_CD,
PRINCIPAL_CD,
BILLING_CD,
CORPORATION_CD
FROM NDW_NRDP_TABLES.NRDP_EPC_MAPPING_DEDUP_P2
GROUP BY 2,3,4,5 
HAVING COUNT(1)>1) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (SYSTEM_CD,PRINCIPAL_CD,BILLING_CD,CORPORATION_CD)
  ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
;
```

The Required output is

```
VT_PASS7PRE=spark.sql(''' SEL
    COUNT(1) CNT,
    SYSTEM_CD,
    PRINCIPAL_CD,
    BILLING_CD,
    CORPORATION_CD
    FROM NDW_NRDP_TABLES.NRDP_EPC_MAPPING_DEDUP_P2
    GROUP BY 2,3,4,5 
    HAVING COUNT(1)>1) ''')
```

I have tried the following code but it is not giving the desired result you can just copy and paste the below code to see the result

```
import re
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

bteq_script = '''
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE VT_PASS7PRE, NO LOG, NO FALLBACK
AS
(
SELECT
COUNT(1) CNT,
SYSTEM_CD,
PRINCIPAL_CD,
BILLING_CD,
CORPORATION_CD
FROM NDW_NRDP_TABLES.NRDP_EPC_MAPPING_DEDUP_P2
GROUP BY 2,3,4,5 
HAVING COUNT(1)>1) WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX (SYSTEM_CD,PRINCIPAL_CD,BILLING_CD,CORPORATION_CD)
  ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
;
'''

create_multi_set_volatile_table_pattern = re.compile(r'CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE (\w+),.*?AS\s*\((.*?)\).*?WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX\s*\((.*?)\)', re.DOTALL | re.IGNORECASE)
create_multi_set_volatile_table_matches = create_multi_set_volatile_table_pattern.finditer(bteq_script)

# Initialize PySpark code with import statements
pyspark_code = f"from pyspark.sql import SparkSession\n" \
               f"from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, DateType, DecimalType\n\n" \
               f"spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('YourAppName').getOrCreate()\n\n"


for match in create_multi_set_volatile_table_matches:
    table_name = match.group(1)
    select_query = match.group(2)

    pyspark_code += f"\n# Creating DataFrame for {table_name}\n"
    pyspark_code += f"{table_name}_df = spark.sql('''{select_query}''')\n"
    pyspark_code += f"{table_name}_df.createOrReplaceTempView('{table_name}')\n"
    pyspark_code += f"{table_name}_df.show()\n\n"

print(pyspark_code)
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is for some kind of migration off Teradata? I don't think regular expressions are nearly powerful enough for this, to do it in a way that is remotely reliable. Maybe broad strokes you could remove the most common flavors of DDL/DML wrappers, but it will inevitably get flummoxed. Add to that Teradata has it's own platform specific syntax/functions that can't get handled with find&replace, you actually have to find the logically equivalent implementation in the target platform.